# bash environment variables not getting exported

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have two shell scripts:

First : `1.sh`, it reads as follows:

```
export PROP="my val"
```

Second : `2.sh`, it reads as follows:

```
./1.sh
echo $PROP
```

Both have execute permission. When I run `2.sh`, I am expecting that environment variable `PROP` set and exported by `1.sh`, is visible to `echo $PROP` statement in `2.sh` and would get printed. But output is blank indicating that PROP is not visible to `2.sh`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sourcing the script in the current process:

```
. 1.sh
echo $PROP
```

And you can then drop `export` altogether:

```
PROP="my val"
```

The problem is that you're running `1.sh` in a new shell process, so any changes it makes to its environment are lost when the process ends.  Specifically, `export` makes the variable available to *children* of the current process, so in this case it cannot affect `2.sh` (the parent process).