Why does compgen behave differently when called which bash -ilc
If I call compgen on bash directly with an environment variable pointing to a directory, it completes paths inside that directory. This can include environment variables if they are no resolved before calling compgen.
> cd /tmp
> mkdir files
> touch files/aa files/ab
> export MY_FILES=/tmp/files
> echo "$MY_FILES/"
/tmp/files
> compgen -v -A file -- "$MY_FILES/"  # not what I want
/tmp/files/ab
/tmp/files/aa
> echo "\$MY_FILES/"
$MY_FILES/
> compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/" # this is what I want
$MY_FILES/ab
$MY_FILES/aa

This works fine when I execute the command but doesn't work when the command is called indirectly (not even in a login shell)
> bash -ilc 'echo "\$MY_FILES/"; compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"'
$MY_FILES/
> echo $?
1

You can tell from the echo command that the escaping works as intended, so this is not an issue with how the string is escaped.
Likewise, putting the line in a script and calling the script doesn't work:
> cat run-compgen
#!/bin/bash -il

echo "\$MY_FILES/"
compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"
echo $?

> ./run-compgen
$MY_FILES/
1

Unsuccessful Solutions

You need a login shell: I tried login and interactive shells, both did not resolve the issue. I now changed the question so this is already included in the examples.
You should not escape the variable: If I do not escape the variable, the command prints something, but not what I want. Please have a look at the first code box in my question. It lists two variants of calling the command. I want the second type of output, not the first. I also thought that \$ might be the wrong way of escaping $, so I tried with 2, 3, or 4 backslashes without success.
The variable is not known in the nested shell: I tried bash -c env and it showed the variable.
This is related to your environment: I tried to exclude this option by also testing inside a clean docker container.

> docker run -it ubuntu bash # start a clean Ubuntu container.
# Then inside the container:
> cd /tmp
> mkdir files
> touch files/aa files/ab
> export MY_FILES=/tmp/files
> bash -ilc 'compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"'


In first case: single quotes and not double quotes.

@Cyrus can you expand on that? What would be the full command?

Within single quotes, the variable MY_FILES is not replaced by its content.

Yes, that is the intent. compgen should see $MY_FILES, not its content.

I wrote about removing the backslash in my original question. It resolves the variable which means the output will have /path/to/files/aa instead of $MY_FILES/aa. This is about tab completing a path containing an environment variable. The variable should NOT be resolved, otherwise the tab completion will expand the variable instead of leaving it in place.

Would this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31153824/26993270

@user202311: I think the situation there is different because the parent process is creating two independent child processes that do not share their environment, whereas in my case there is only one parent and one child.

@chepner, was this an answer to my question or to one of the other comments? I think compgen should expand the variable itself, i.e., it should be called with the name of the variable, as a string, and then figure out that this is a variable internally. Is that what you meant?

@Flogo Sorry, deleting comment; I confused myself going down some irrelevant rabbit hole.

@Flogo: Sorry, I was wondering if . ./run-compgen would work.

This works on bash 5.3-alpha. Perhaps it was a bug...

A recent discussion about it on the mailing list: https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2023-06/msg00094.html

compgen is for completion. Completion is only available in interactive bash session! So you have to bash -ic 'compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"' ;echo $? .

In the script, replace shebang by #!/bin/bash -i

If you write "\$MY_FILES/", the backslash escapes the $, and no parameter expansion will occur. Remove the backslash.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I tried adding -i and -l to both the call and the script with no success. Did you try your suggestion and did it work for you?

@user1934428 I answered the same point a few comments above already: Not expanding the variable is on purpose. I want compgen to see the name of the variable, not its content.

@Flogo Yes, I've tried both: bash -ic 'compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"' ;echo $? and adding a -i in script's shebang, both work fine on my bash 5.2.15. But this don't work under bash 5.0.3.

But could you tell me how you plan to use completion in a non interactive script?

I'm on bash 5.2.21 (default on Ubuntu 24.04) so unless it was broken again after fixing it for 5.2.15, I should have the fix as well.
The intended use for this is as part of an tab completion script. The Python package argcomplete uses a call like this to programmatically access the file completions: https://github.com/kislyuk/argcomplete/blob/develop/argcomplete/completers.py#L67 I'm trying to debug this and also do something similar for a non-Python project. The context is interactive and I also tried keeping it interactive with bash -ic.

Just tried with fresh bash 5.2.32, this work fine.

I tried it again in a docker container to exclude any issues coming from specific setup on my machine. It still did not work. Here is the exact list of commands I used:
docker run -it ubuntu bash to start a clean Ubuntu container. Then inside the container: mkdir files; touch files/aa files/ab; export MY_FILES=$(pwd)/files to set everything up. Finally bash -ilc 'compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"' to test. Does this also work for you?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub can you try the example I posted above in Docker? What do you mean exactly with "works fine"? Can you post the exact commands you tried and the output you got? Copy-pasting the command you posted earlier prints no output from the first command and an exit code of 1 from the echo $? for me.

This was fixed in bash 5.3. The temporary solution is to call bind at the beginning of the command, which works with any shell (login, interactive, normal) but generates a warning unless used with an interactive shell:
bash -ic 'bind; compgen -v -A file -- "\$MY_FILES/"'

(https://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?111125)
